# Remove certain text from text box on click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have a `TextBox`control in my web form, where in I display Height & Width of certain product.

Now I display this as follows :

[image]

As you can see, I append a `"` to show inches, in the string in the following way :

```
txtH.Text = arrHW[i].ToString() + "\"";
```

Now, this causes problem while editing! As the user can never always be sure of correctly editing the field by editing the **number** only and not the `"` symbol.

I need someway either through JavaScript or C#, that removes the symbol `"` while the user clicks on the textbox and removes as the focus is changed.

I tried this method, but it doesn't seem to work!

```
protected void txtH_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string height = txtH.Text;
            char[] splitArr = { '"' };
            string[] editH = height.Split(splitArr);

            for (int i = 0; i < editH.Length; i++)
            {
                if (editH[i].ToString().Equals("\""))
                {
                    editH[i].Remove(i);
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the designer code for the textboxes :

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcHW" runat="server">
       <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-arrows-v"></i>&nbsp;Height</span>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtH" runat="server" Width="60px" CssClass="form-control" OnTextChanged="txtH_TextChanged" />

              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-arrows-h"></i>&nbsp;Width</span>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtW" runat="server" Width="60px" CssClass="form-control" />
       </div>
 </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Comment: You can just replace it with empty string on focus and then again add on focus lose, if there is some value

Comment: Why add " in the textbox in the first place. Just note the units are in inches or have a select that denotes what the units are that the user can pick.

Comment: @Lali : i would appreciate if you would show me some demo

Comment: Why not just add (in inches) to your label as you have done for Price directly below - far less complicated

Comment: @epascarello : Client's requirement !! I need to display it that way.. Is there some way to show it in background like placeholder or faded ?

Comment: In that case, add an additional label directly after

Comment: @PaulF : I have kept that temporarily! If this could be possible then it would be helpful! Otherwise I have to that the other way as in `Price`

Comment: Why don't you just check to see if the " is there onblur. If not, add it to the end? Removing the " onfocus is possible, but the placement of the cursor can be an issue.

Comment: @PaulF :  Please see my updated question! I have added the design code in the question! Adding a label to that would spoil the design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the text box as soon as the focus is on it then add`"`  after the user adds the value to it! **This is one way of doing it!**

```
var prev="";
$('#HEIGHT').focus(function() {
prev=$(this).val();
$(this).val(prev.replace("\"", ""));

}).blur(function() {

 if($(this).val()==""){
 $(this).val(prev)
}
else{
$(this).val($(this).val()+"\"");
}
});
```

Comment: That is not correct. You remove the whole string, not what OP wants

Comment: exactly.. What if the users just clicks on the text box and doesnt edit.. it will  remove the value

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh In the accepted answer if the user doesent enter anything it woul still have " as the value!

Comment: That is not possible because I do not show the textboxes at all if there is a null value in DB for Height Width. Height Width are shown according to category of products

Comment: WHAT IF USER MANUALLY REMOVES THE VALUE FROM THE TEXTBOX THEN?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88095/discussion-between-psylogic-and-abhishek-ghosh).

Comment: MY EDITED ANSWER WILL PREVENT IT IN ALL CASES!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("TextBoxId").focus(function(){
        var tval = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(tval.replace(/\"/g, ""));
    });

    $("TextBoxId").focusout(function(){
        var tval = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(tval.replace(/\"/g, "")+ '\"');
    });
});
```

Comment: This will work if the user only allowed to enter number

Comment: Yes, @epascarello, I modified

Answer (score 1):

Without any jquery:

```
(function($el) {
    "use strict";    

    $el.addEventListener("focus", adjust, true);
    $el.addEventListener("blur", adjust, true);

    function adjust($e) {
        var e = $e.type;
        if (e === "focus") $el.value = $el.value.replace(/\"/g, ""); 
        if (e === "blur")  $el.value = $el.value + '"';     
    }    

})(document.getElementById("height"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dlizik/5cb7g8te/

Comment: User can enter `"` so you can get multiple "

Comment: honesty I think the best solution is to separate the styling concern from the data concern; just put the quote mark in a separate span :)

Comment: will this add a `"` if i supply the value from the backend??

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh no; you can pre-supply a value with html alone http://jsfiddle.net/dlizik/5cb7g8te/1/

Comment: what does `"use-strict";` do ?

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh it does a lot of things; but it's main purpose is to force you to write cleaner code so you waste less time debugging.

Comment: Thank you for the time.. But one of the answers provided in other solution suits my need to the closest! Thanks anyways !

Answer (score 1):

I have tried solving your issue with this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/akd7r31a/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#username').focus(function(){
        var txtValue = $(this).val();
        var charTest = txtValue.substr(txtValue.length - 1);
        if(charTest == '"'){
            var showString = txtValue.slice(0, -1);
            $(this).val(showString);
        }
    });

    $('#username').focusout(function(){
        var txtValue = $(this).val();
        var charTest = txtValue.substr(txtValue.length - 1);
        if(charTest != '"'){
            var newVal = $(this).val() + '"';
            $(this).val(newVal);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I do not understand how this solves my issue ? It doesnt add " to the string or removes it ? have u tested the fiddle ?  And my text box isnt a username its a Height,Width text box

Comment: sorry , iforgot to add jquery library to my fiddle. it works fine now

Comment: You can change the name of your textbox as you wish, just replace the `username` with your own id

Comment: This is exactly what I needed ...! Though very trivial .. glad you had the solution! Thank you so much!

Comment: I changed my *accepted answer* because in the case where text box becomes empty, instead of adding the old value only the `"` are added